# Verifying a proof related to modular operations

Tags: modular-arithmetic, divisibility

I have a formula of the form: $$F(x,y)=ax^2+by=0$$
where $a,x,b$ and $y$ are integers.
I made the following steps:
Since  $$F(x,y)=ax^2+by=0$$
then  $$F(x,y)=ax^2+by=0 \pmod{x^2}$$
then I get $$by=0\pmod{x^2}$$
and finaly, there exists some integer $c$ verifying
$$by=cx^2$$
I cannot confirm that the above steps are correct.

My **question** is: is the above analysis remains true when replacing $x^2$ by any other positive integer $m$.

Comment: In fact, $c=-a$

Comment: You **really** don’t need modular arithmetic to get this. $ax^2+by=0$ means $by=-ax^2.$

Comment: Is this all you are trying to prove? What is your question?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: My **question** is: is the above analysis remain true when replacing $x^2$ by any other positive integer $m$.

Comment: This kid of reason, while unnecessary here, can be useful in other sorts of problems.

Comment: Yes, $\,am\!+\!by=0\Rightarrow -am=by\Rightarrow m\mid by,\,$ and it also follows by reducing $\,am\!+\!by=0\,\bmod m$.

**Generally** if $\,a_1 + \cdots a_j = a_{j+1}+\cdots a_k\,$ and $\,m\,$ divides all the $\,a_n\,$ except possibly $\,a_i\,$ then $\,m\mid a_i\,$ too, since reducing $\bmod m\,$ yields $\,a_i\equiv 0.\, $ Here $\ x\mid y\, $ means $\,x\,$ divides $\,y,\,$ i.e. $\,nx = y\,$ for some integer $\,n.\ \ $